# COMPARE 2 or more .PROPERTIES files comparing ONLY keys

Tags: java, properties, compare, file-comparison

I want to compare 2 or more (if posible) .properties files, exactly are i18n files.
So I have the default messages_es.properties where I first add the keys with values, what I really need is to compare only the keys of the default/primary messages_es.properties with other .properties file for example messages_en.properties, to know which translations are left on different .properties files.

Basically:

- Input: Two properties files
- Output: Missing keys on the 2nd .properties file

The O/P should show the keys missing on the 2nd .properties files.

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `Properties` has methods

```
public synchronized void load(InputStream inStream)
public synchronized void load(Reader reader)
```

You can use them to load your files.

Then use method

```
public Set<String> stringPropertyNames()
```

To get set of properties.

Finally `Set` has methods

```
boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)
boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c)
```

To work with difference.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for answer, I implemented below code

```
public class PropertiesCompare {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String propertiesFilename1 = System.getProperty("PropFile1");
    String propertiesFilename2 = System.getProperty("PropFile2");

    Map<String, String> PropFile1 = getProps(propertiesFilename1);
    Map<String, String> PropFile2 = getProps(propertiesFilename2);

    String missingProp = "";

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : PropFile1.entrySet()) {
        if (PropFile2.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            String PropFile2Value = (PropFile2.get(entry.getKey()));
            String PropFile1Value = (entry.getValue());

            if (!PropFile2Value.equalsIgnoreCase(PropFile1Value)) {
                 System.out.println("Key : "+entry.getKey()+"\t\nValue : PropFile1 = "+PropFile1Value+", PropFile2 = "+PropFile2Value);
            }
        } else {
            missingProp= missingProp+(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
        }
    }
}

public static Map<String, String> getProps(String propertiesFilename1) {
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(propertiesFilename1)) {
        Properties prop = new Properties() {
            @Override
            public synchronized Object put(Object key, Object value) {
                return properties.put(key.toString(), value.toString());
            }
        };
        prop.load(stream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return properties;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Example (very simple)

```
String filename1 = args[0];
String filename2 = args[1];
try {
  System.out.println("Load " + filename1);
  Properties prop1 = loadProperties(filename1);
  Properties prop2 = loadProperties(filename2);

  Set<String> proprietes1 = prop1.stringPropertyNames();
  Set<String> proprietes2 = prop2.stringPropertyNames();
  proprietes1.removeAll(proprietes2);
  System.out.println("Propriétés de " + filename1 + " qui ne sont pas dans " + filename2);
  for (String prop : proprietes1) {
    System.out.println(prop);
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
  System.out.println(usage);
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where:

```
public static Properties loadProperties(String filename1) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename1));
  prop.load(reader);
  return prop;
}
```